# Ruby using each_with_index

Tags: arrays, ruby, each, puts

I'd like this method to circle through each item in the array of names `katz_deli` and use `puts` to display the name and its index.  However, the output is just the *first* name in the array with its index.

My code:

```
def line (katz_deli)
  if katz_deli.count > 1
    katz_deli.each_with_index {|name, index| puts "The line is currently: #{index +1}. #{name}" }
  else
    puts "The line is currently empty."
  end
end
```

I want my output to be `"The line is currently: 1. Logan 2. Avi 3. Spencer"`
But I'm getting `"The line is currently: 1. Logan."` Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that you have more than one element in your array? if yes, please provide an example of your array's data

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When I call `line([ "Logan", "Avi", "Spencer" ])` I get three lines of output: `The line is currently: 1. Logan`, `The line is currently: 2. Avi`, and `The line is currently: 3. Spencer`.

Comment: The array is katz_deli = ["Logan", "Avi", "Spencer"].  I see.  Is there a way to get this get this all on one line---i.e for the output to be exactly  `The line is currently: 1. Logan 2. Avi 3. Spencer`  I'm doing this for a course and I think that's what the instructors are looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the output string at first, and `puts` it once it is ready:

```
input = ["Logan", "Avi", "Spencer"]

def line (katz_deli)
  if katz_deli.count > 1
    output = "The line is currently:"
    katz_deli.each_with_index do |name, index|
      output << " #{index +1}. #{name}"
    end
    puts output
  else
    puts "The line is currently empty."
  end
end

line(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def line (katz_deli)
  if katz_deli.count > 1
    print "The line is currently:"
    katz_deli.each_with_index {|name, index|  print " #{index +1}. #{name}" }
  else
    puts "The line is currently empty."
  end
end
```